# Rails calling controller methods with different formats depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller

I'm trying to determine why my test environment behaves differently than my development environment.  If I run a standard `bundle exec rails s` (so in the dev environment) and I access one of my routes through Chrome, `localhost:3000/advertiser_types`, the log shows that the request is processed as JSON:

```
Started GET "/advertiser_types" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-03 14:08:18 -0600
Processing by AdvertiserTypesController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Advertiser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "advertisers".* FROM "advertisers"  WHERE "advertisers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 3.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

If I run `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails s` and try to access the same page, the request is processed as HTML instead and throws an exception since my controller only returns JSON.

```
Started GET "/advertiser_types" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-03 14:07:00 -0600
Processing by AdvertiserTypesController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Advertiser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "advertisers".* FROM "advertisers"  WHERE "advertisers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "feeds"  WHERE "feeds"."advertiser_id" = $1  [["advertiser_id", 3]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 4ms
Reporting exception: ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

The controller code looks like this:

```
class AdvertiserTypesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    advertiser_types = AdvertiserType.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: advertiser_types}
    end
  end
end
```

Why is the exact same request being processed differently depending on the environment I'm in?  I can't figure out what the cause is.  My guess is that there's some sort of config somewhere that needs to be modified, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error using Capybara/Webkit.  Apparently my test environment lacks authenticity tokens to allow these requests to function properly.  Allowing forgery protection in my rspec configuration allowed me to get this to behave correctly with Webkit and Selenium.